# Required file "" missing after not using visual c++ for a while

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I haven't used visual c++ in a while, and i went to run an old project today, getting the following error

```
1>------ Build started: Project: cons, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets(62,5): error : Required file "" is missing.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

No idea what it means, but to make sure it wasn't just that specific solution, i created one of the template console solutions built into visual c++ and got the same error... how can i fix this?

edit: Ok, after some investigation, it seems i'm unable to include a bunch of standard headers... stdio, string, iostream, etc, they all seem to be missing... any idea why? i have also just performed a repair installation of visual studio 2010

Comment: I typed your error message to google: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4e28136c-a830-4f7a-b60a-62143b0bb4f0/microsoftcppwin32targets575-error-required-file-is-missing?forum=msbuild
Does it help?

Comment: No, that's the first thing i did, this seems to be a different error.

Comment: :/,  at worst case you can reinstall VS. Or install a newer one, i am pretty sure this would solve the problem without much effort.

Comment: Could you raise the verbosity of the build log output and reproduce the error? 
`Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity > Diagnostic`

Answer (score 0):

The part of the `.Targets` file has a comment `<!-- Precompiled headers - need to build them first -->`

So I would guess you have your project set to use a precompiled header but deleted the name of the header.

Check the project properties at "C/C++"->"Precompiled Headers".
Either set the value of `Precompiled Header` to `Not Using Precompiled Headers` or enter the name of the precompiled header file (default=`stdafx.h`) as value for `Precompiled Header File`.

Comment: Just checked, it's set to the default stdafx.h, changing the settings to not use it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Which toolset is configured for your Project? `Project settings->Configuration Properties->General->Platform Toolset`

Comment: I have tried both options, which are "v90" or "v100"